# List issue during upgrade from Terraform 0.11 to 0.12

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I have a problem trying to rewrite a list to work in Terraform 0.12
that works in Terraform 0.11.

This is my list:

```
variable "master_authorized_networks_config" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "The list of CIDR blocks of master authorized networks."

  default = [
    {
      cidr_blocks = [
        { 
          cidr_block   = "XXXXXX/32"
          display_name = "XXXXX"
        },
        { 
          cidr_block   = "XXXXXX/32"
          display_name = "XXXXX"
        },
        { 
          cidr_block   = "XXXXXX/32"
          display_name = "XXXXX"
        },
        { 
          cidr_block   = "XXXXXX/32"
          display_name = "XXXXX"
        },
      ]
    },
  ]
```

I added it to module:
`master_authorized_networks_config = var.master_authorized_networks_config`

After running `terraform apply` I get the following error:

```
Error: Invalid default value for variable

  on ../../modules/xxx/xxx/variables.tf line 71, in variable "master_authorized_networks_config":
  71:   default = [
  72:     {
  73:       cidr_blocks = [
  74:         {
  75:           cidr_block   = "XXXXXX/32"
  76:           display_name = "XXXXX"
  77:         },
  78:         {
  79:           cidr_block   = "XXXXXX/32"
  80:           display_name = "XXXXX"
  81:         },
  82:         {
  83:           cidr_block   = "XXXXXX/32"
  84:           display_name = "XXXXX"
  85:         },
  86:         {
  87:           cidr_block   = "XXXXXX/32"
  88:           display_name = "XXXXX"
  89:         },
 102:       ]
 103:     },
 104:   ]

This default value is not compatible with the variable's type constraint:
element 0: string required.
```

I can't resolve this problem. Can you help me?

Comment: It's not a list of strings. You should set the type to be `list(object)` or remove the type part altogether and allow Terraform to work out the type from the default. The second option is what I'd do.

Comment: `list(string)` was not an allowed type specification in 0.11. Are you sure you were using this successfully with 0.11?

Comment: Pretty sure they've ran `0.12upgrade` when they had `type = "list"` before and ended up with that. It's been a long time since my 0.12 upgrade but I think that was the default behaviour of the tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is telling you that your default value doesn't match the type constraint that you've told Terraform about with `type = list(string)`. That type constraint says that it must be a list of strings and is the default coming from 0.11 via the `0.12upgrade` tool that you may have ran to get that output if you had `type = list` previously.

You could change your type constraint to be `list(object)`. If you simplified your data structure so that you just had a list of objects with `cidr_block` and `display_name` keys instead of a list of objects with key `cidr_blocks` that has a list of the aforementioned objects then you could even go as far as validating that more precisely:

```
variable "master_authorized_networks_config" {
  type = list(object{
    cidr_block   = string
    display_name = string
  })

  description = "The list of CIDR blocks of master authorized networks."

  default = [
    { 
      cidr_block   = "XXXXXX/32"
      display_name = "XXXXX"
    },
# ...
  ]
}
```

Or, much simpler, when providing a default you can choose to let Terraform infer the expected object type automatically by removing the `type` parameter from the variable. Then if anyone attempts to pass in a variable that doesn't match the type of the default Terraform will tell you at plan or validate time.